Frame ID of upper level function in function stack in Python
I'm trying to obtain the actual frame address of a function's stack using Python's inspect module. However, when I print the frame addresses of two different inner functions within a caller function, I notice that the caller's address differs between the two inner functions. Here's the code illustrating the issue:
import inspect

def inner_function1():
    for frame_info in inspect.stack()[:2]:
        print(frame_info.function, hex(id(frame_info)))

def inner_function2():
    for frame_info in inspect.stack()[:2]:
        print(frame_info.function, hex(id(frame_info)))

def caller():
    inner_function1()
    print(30*"-")
    inner_function2()

caller()

Actual results:
inner_function1 0x786436cfb2e0
caller 0x786436cfb3a0
------------------------------
inner_function2 0x786436cfb3a0
caller 0x786436cfb2e0

Ideal results:
inner_function1 0x786436cfb2e0
caller 0x786436cfb3a0
------------------------------
inner_function2 0x786436cfb3a0
caller 0x786436cfb3a0

Is there a way to get the same address for caller in both cases?

upper_level? did you mean get_up_fun?

I'm not sure what you think you are printing there.  The frame object isn't necessarily related to the function in any way.  They get reclaimed and reused.
